# Sending clipboard paste with PostMessage() and/or hooking

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, clipboard

I use Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 and Windows 7.
There is one program, which has windows with text boxes.
Text boxes (and other control elements) are not EDIT or any other class windows in GDI, so program renders and handles it by itself.
The question is: how to do clipboard paste to it?

First of all I tried `WM_PASTE` with `PostMessage()`.It does not work at all. Maybe `WM_PASTE` message is not handled by application.

Second, I tried to send 4 messages with `PostMessage()`: two `WM_KEYDOWN` messages with `VK_CONTROL` and `V` and two `WM_KEYUP` messages. It resulted in printing "V" in text box. Unfortunately, `WM_CHAR` is generated after `WM_KEYDOWN` with `V`.

Next, I hooked `PeekMessageW()` function to get control of program message loop. There I returned four simulated messages: two `WM_KEYDOWN`'s and two `WM_KEYUP`'s. Does not work. Tried this hack on `notepad.exe` in debugger. Does not work too.

Next, I sent `WM_CHAR` with `0x16` to simulate <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> message. Works on other windows, does not work on the window of the app.

How can I get it to work? I can load my code to this process and hook something if it is needed. Where and when is clipboard paste processed?

And no, I can not use `SendInput()` or `keybd_event()`. Just no. Window is not active and is not attached to direct keyboard input.

Comment: Since the program in question uses window-less controls, you cannot send messages. Your only chance for success is [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable: nothing in the question says the controls are window-less, only that they are not standard `EDIT` controls. They could still be windowed and just be custom-painted. Handling `WM_PASTE` is not a requirement for custom controls, and UI Automation of a custom control would only work if the app implements `IAccessible` and handles `WM_GETOBJECT`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: *"are not EDIT **or any other class windows**"*.

Comment: @IInspectable: "*or any other class windows **in GDI***" - could still mean the controls are windowed and just using custom classes instead of standard system classes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I ignored the GDI bit, since windows are USER objects, not GDI objects.

Comment: @deselect: do the text boxes have their own `HWND`s? Verify with Spy++ or similar tool. Does copy/paste via keyboard work normally on the text boxes? Does Spy++ show paste messages being sent to the text boxes?

Comment: @deselect: [You can’t simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513), so your only options are `WM_PASTE`, `SendInput()`, or [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx). If the text boxes do not accept `WM_PASTE`, if you cannot simulate `CTRL+V`, and if UI Automation is supported, then you would have to read the clipboard text yourself and use UI Automation to insert the text characters into the text boxes directly.

Comment: First. Text boxes do not have their own HWND's. Second. `PostMessage()` works when I send messages to the whole big window (and textbox has a focus). I can simulate any keyboard input I want, also arrow keys and Home/End keys are working.

Comment: Please help me with low-level solution. I know it is possible because program handles Ctrl+V (or Shift+Ins) correctly when I press it on keyboard. I can do any hooking, any hacking, but it is overkill to use UI Automation ONLY for clipboard (all is working except clipboard).

Comment: Why the obsession with hacking and input faking? Why not use the automation API?

Comment: Because code is almost ready and it is overkill to use UI Automation in code that does not even use COM. Also problem is solved now - with `GetKeyState()` hooking.

Comment: Hooking `GetKeyState` may appear to solve the issues you have with one particular application. But it certainly will break other applications. The link posted by [Remy Lebeau](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38646850/sending-clipboard-paste-with-postmessage-and-or-hooking#comment64677406_38646850) above explains the dangers. It's not like you didn't know...

Comment: Ah, the Concorde fallacy